# Reset total for each vendor, sum up for each vendor, in a buyer's cart

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the problem:
[image: Diagram]

Each item costs $200.00, so that makes a total of $3,000 for 15 items.

The items are from different vendors, so I need to get the total per Vendor according to the quantity the buyer chose. How is this achieved?

The code works as expected, until I try to get the grand_totals per vendor.

```
<?php
$user_ref = '00007939789';

$grand_total = 0;
$sellers = array();

$fetch_sellers = mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT s_c_vendor 
  FROM shopping_cart 
 WHERE s_c_user_ref='$user_ref' 
 GROUP 
    BY s_c_vendor
");

if (mysqli_num_rows($fetch_sellers) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_sellers)) {
        array_push($sellers, $row['s_c_vendor']);
}

for ($i=0; $i < count($sellers); $i++) { 
    $get_products = mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT s_c_product
     , s_c_qty 
  FROM shopping_cart 
 WHERE s_c_user_ref='$user_ref' 
   AND s_c_vendor = '$sellers[$i]' 
");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($get_products) > 0) {
        while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_products)) {
            echo "Product Title: ";
            $product_ref = $row1['s_c_product'];
            echo $product_ref;
            echo " Qty: ";
            echo $row1['s_c_qty'];
            $qty = $row1['s_c_qty'];
            echo "<br>";

            $get_subtotal = mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT L_PRICE price 
  FROM listings 
 WHERE L_REF = '$product_ref' 
");

            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_subtotal)) {
                $price = $row2['price'];
                $subtotal = $row2['price'] * $qty;
                echo "Price: ".number_format($price)." ";
                echo "Subtotal: ".number_format($subtotal)."<br><br>";
            }

            $get_grandtotal = mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT SUM(L_PRICE) grand_total 
  FROM listings 
 WHERE v_ref = '$sellers[$i]' 
");
            $grand_total += mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_grandtotal)['grand_total'];

        }
        echo "<h2>Grand Total for seller ".$sellers[$i]." : ".$grand_total."</h2>";
    }
}

}
```

There are multiple tables in my database, which are shown in diagrams below.

[image: Listing Table]
[image: Shopping Cart Table]

Comment: this example probably cannot be more over-complicated than it is; simply use `SUM(L_PRICE)` and `GROUP BY s_c_vendor`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I tried that, and multiple other syntaxes. It's always either giving the totals for All vendors, or it's only grabbing the 'last' subtotal per vendor.

Comment: @MartinZeitler What do you recommend if that didn't work? (Totals still displaying incorrectly)

Comment: @anna your failure to apply the suggestion does not imply, that it's a bad suggestion... `SUM()` is a domain aggregate function, where `GROUP BY` defines the domain (getting the same result means, there is only one vendor in the domain). the expectation, to get an answer by providing the table names, might not be fulfilled.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Sorry I did not understand that. I applied the suggestion, and it gives the exact same result as my current one... I edited the question to include the table 'breakdowns' as well. What else is required to clarify?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Edited the question - I just screenshot the results and added a diagram of the problem (and which results are sought)

Comment: Why you are looking grand total in listings table? You just summarize all items for each seller. You have to select only products that in your cart and in first time you get 1800 that you think is correct, but it's not, it's matched only because total amount of all products for first seller that selling (not only that in cart) are 1800. To see that just add one more product for this seller in listinigs but don't add it to cart and you will see the difference. You need use join and clean up your code: make a split between db queries and logic, load all necessary data first.

Comment: @amedv If I understand you correctly, you're saying that the current totals are wrong because the seller does not have more than the listed items? I've got 14,000 rows in the listings table, and every seller has about 50-100 listings each. I check the listings table for grand_totals cause that's the only place where the prices are kept..and then multiplied by the quantity displayed in the buyer's cart. This is about the 5th different approach I used, which is closest to the final result (except that grand_totals are not matching up). How do you recommend I correct it at this stage?

Comment: Yes, that's I said. I understand why you looking into this table, but logic looks like you just summarize all items for each seller that it sells in general, doesn't matter if it in cart or not. Just run simple queries in sql table without php to calculate and count to check.

Comment: @amedv nope, as you may notice it first does a check to display items that are in a buyer's cart... Then a new query gets the info of the products by that filter.

Comment: MySQL doesn't know what you do in PHP it operate only by sql-queries and in last query you load all products from listings for specific seller, doesn't matter is it in cart or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change last SQL query to:

```
$get_grandtotal = mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT SUM(L_PRICE) grand_total 
  FROM listings 
 WHERE v_ref = '$sellers[$i]' AND L_REF = '$product_ref'
");
```

Set `$grand_total = 0;` right where is `for` loop opened:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($sellers); $i++) { 
        $grand_total = 0;
        $get_products = ....
        ...
```

And read my comment above.

Comment: Wow, you did it! Resetting the grand_total to 0 where you indicated was the key. I had to make some extra changes: I altered the grand_total variable to `$grand_total += mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_grandtotal)['grand_total'] * $qty;` and it worked! Thanks for the help, mate :-)